# VSPackage did not load correctly; How to revert "continue to show this error message" status?

Tags: visual-studio, vspackage

Today the VSPackage I'm developing failed to load, and Visual Studio prompted me to check ActivityLog.xml. It also asked "continue to show this error message?" And accidentally I pressed no.

The window I'm referring to looks similar to this:
[image: Picture of Visual Studio dialog window where I pressed No instead of Yes]

**How can I revert pressing "No"?**

I couldn't find any switches in Tools>Options.
This seems like a difficult phrase to search on google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you press No, Visual Studio creates a registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\VS_VERSION\Packages{YOUR_PACKAGE_GUID} (e.g. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Packages{9A7EBB7F-B08C-4E35-9898-A7B73468A624}) with a value SkipLoading=1.

You need to delete this **SkipLoading**.

Answer (score 4):

Just start Visual Studio with this switch:

devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs

Answer (score 0):

For Visual studio 2017 or newer this is slightly trickier.

Close all instances of visual studio.
Open regedit.

Select `"HKEY_USERS"`.

From `"File"` menu select `"Load Hive"`.

and locate visual studio's private registry hive file, which should be named "privateregistry.bin", could reside for example:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_014d6a62\privateregistry.bin`

```
15 = vs2017
16 = vs2019
```

rest of version is installation / configuration specific.

If you get error like this:

```
[Window Title]
Load Hive

[Content]
privateregistry.bin
This file is in use.
Enter a new name or close the file that’s open in another program.

[OK]
```

Need to wait visual studio to shutdown or close / terminate them manually.

in appearing dialog give some name, for example "vs2015_reghive"

Browse under path

```
HKEY_USERS\vs2015_reghive\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_014d6a62\Packages
```

and scroll all Packages in there and delete all "SkipLoading" keys there.

Then select your main key `HKEY_USERS\vs2015_reghive`, and from menu - `"File"` > `"Unload Hive"`.

Start Visual studio normally.